# Can somebody help explain how one of two AA batteries in series is being changed to emit a negative charge?

Tags: batteries

This, I have never seen before and I can not explain, and I have no idea how this can even be.

I have one of those outside temperature sensors. La Crosse model TX37U-IT https://www.lacrossetechnology.com/products/tx37u-it

The sensor thing is outside in the cold and it transmits to the base unit in the house.

The outside sensor unit takes 2 AA batteries.

I've had this thing for probably 10 years now. and it's worked fine.
A few months ago, maybe a year or so by now, it's started chewing through batteries.

I usually use rechargeables because that's how I roll, and they usually last a while and I recharge them and all is well.

But here's what's started happening recently.
Usually a charge will last many months if not a year or two.
now a charge will last a few months tops.

And Here's The Weird Part.

When I test the 2 AA batteries from the sensor after it stops working, one of them reads a bit low like 1.2 volts, and the other one reads NEGATIVE .1 or so volts.

And it's always the one in the same position in the device.

The first time I saw this, I figured it was a bad rechargeable battery. I threw them out.
The second time, the same thing happened, seemed a bit fishy.

So most recently, I put in two fresh brand new AA duracell batteries, not rechargeable. They should last YEARS in this thing.
And just now after maybe a month, the thing isn't working again, one battery is at 1.2v and the other is at -0.2

How is this even possible?

Okay, so now that it's been sitting here for a few minutes, the -0.2 has gone positive to 0.1
So something must be forcibly backfeeding it?

Except it's in series with the other battery. How can whatever's going on possibly affect one battery and not the other?

Yet it keeps happening.

I'm stumped, but I know nothing about electricity so that's to be expected, but is there some obvious or rational explanation for this? I've never seen anything behave this way with batteries.

Comment: Something's gone wrong with the sensor, causing excessive quiescent current. Reverse charging is definitely possible, but normally only occurs when you mix old and new batteries (this is why you're told not to do that); this would appear to be a strange system that uses both batteries independently instead of just putting them in series...

Comment: I'd love for that to be the answer but... they ARE in series.

Comment: There's definitely something pulling current from one battery that isn't going through the other.

Comment: Are you sure its only in series? And not tapping the center and both ends? Some devices will use half a battery pack for some things and the full pack for other things. Or that there isn't a short in the battery holder?

Comment: it's a pretty standard looking battery case, it takes 2 AA batteries and they're facing opposite directions, and one has the contacts attached. nothing fancy going on here as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 4):

> And just now after maybe a month, the thing isn't working again, one battery is at 1.2v and the other is at -0.2.
> How is this even possible?

> Okay, so now that it's been sitting here for a few minutes, the -0.2 has gone positive to 0.1 So something must be forcibly backfeeding it? Except it's in series with the other battery. How can whatever's going on possibly affect one battery and not the other?

Because the thing that's "forcibly backfeeding it" is *the other battery*. Think about it. Let's say that the "bad" battery is the one attached to the device's positive terminal. The bad battery's negative terminal is directly connected to the good battery's positive terminal, and the bad battery's positive terminal is indirectly (through the electronics of the temperature sensor) connected to the good battery's negative terminal.

This is *always happening* when you have a series connection. When the two batteries have an equal state of charge then no current flows (except whatever the device uses) and nothing bad happens. But when one battery is dead and the other still has some charge, it results in the dead one "reverse charging".

So nothing freaky weird is happening except that one battery is dying a little bit before the other. Why is that? Well, maybe it's just coincidence that every time you checked, it's a certain one that died. Maybe one is a little bit warmer or colder than the other. Or maybe there's some crud in the battery compartment that is short-circuiting the one battery (not a short in the sense of 0 ohms, but a short in the sense that it provides a path between the two terminals of the battery that doesn't go through the device that it's supposed to be powering). We can't really say. You haven't found a smoking gun.

Comment: May also be that the batteries get differently sun or cold wind, so they operate in different ambient conditions?

Comment: okay to the reigning theme which certainly is viable is the crud or corrosion in the gizmo. this is an outside sensor and it's been outside (under an overhang, but still outside) for years now, so I can totally see some corrosion due to humidity and rust and whatnot. thanks. I will go give it a clean and see what happens. I just never knew this was a thing, never thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure , the thing happening is polarity reversal, as evident from the name , in this the polarity of a cell gets reversed , a very common phenomenon for batteries in series.

I am unaware of the circuit, the device you mention is using , but it is tending to  nearly deplete one of your batteries before the other one..

now consider one battery as X and other as Y , Y is nearly depleted fully , but X still has potential energy so the circuit will still use that potential and current will pass through the depleted battery Y

the scenario is

```
-[0000]+  -[0000]+ _______circuit 
   x          y

   -[0000]+
      Y
<------------  flow of electrons
```

this leads to opposite charge accumulation
and thus the battery starts getting  reversed polarized...it  is common when new batteries are used with old , one gets depleted before the other , in your case it might have been a manufacture defect from the  company  who made the cells.

Comment: Your batteries going negative is normal when depleted, it is charged from the other battery. If you can open the unit up and thoroughly clean it. Over the years it has picked up contamination that is somewhat conductive that is causing your batteries to discharge, most likely, or one of the semiconductors has failed.

Comment: this has happened at least 3 times and the most recently time was with 2 brand new batteries from the same pack. But I'm liking the sound of the contamination causing uneven discharge. Thanks for the explanation.